# Calling Firebase Cloud Functions Locally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, aws-cloud9

I know this question has been asked many times, and I've read all the answers, but still don't have a working solution.

I try to run my firebase functions and hosting locally with `firebase serve` or `firebase emulators:start` [as described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#test-locally) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator).

This gives me something like:

```
✔  functions: Using node@8 from host.
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://127.0.0.1:8081
i  functions: Watching "/home/ec2-user/environment/functions" for Cloud Functions...
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: build
✔  hosting: Local server: http://127.0.0.1:8080
⚠  functions: Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to XXXXX-d5435114eb69.json. Non-emulated services will access production using these credentials. Be careful!
✔  functions[log]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:8081/XXXXX/us-central1/log).
```

The hosting server works perfectly, and there is a `log` cloud function initialized at `http://127.0.0.1:8081/XXXXX/us-central1/log`. But running:

```
const log = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('log');
log("Hello World");
```

from the local hosted site tries to call the deployed cloud function and gives me a CORS error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-XXXXX.cloudfunctions.net/log' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy

I'm using the [firebase auto configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#sdk_auto-configuration) to load the sdk.

Is it possible to run both hosting and functions locally for development?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my solution was simple, I used `https.onRequest` instead of `https.onCall`:

Not working:

```js
// Cloud Function
exports.testFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
})
```

Working:

```js
// Cloud Function
exports.testFunction = functions.https.onCall(() => {
  return { message: "Hello from Firebase!" }
})
```

Maybe that's your issue too?

Comment: That would work. But it changes how you call the functions from the client.